# Should I use a View Model? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am populating a view in my ASP.NET MVC application. I have quite a bit of data that has to be loaded after the page based on user input, thus I am making an Ajax call to get this data. I do not want to have to reload the page to get the data.

Correct me if I'm using the wrong term (I've seen it a bit over the past week), but the data being loaded from Ajax is *idempotent*, it will be used for display only; the user will not update the data as input.

***What I am wondering is if the fields for the data that I am getting in the Ajax call still should be defined in the View Model?***

Consider the following code:

**ProfileViewModel.cs**

```
public class ProfileViewModel
{
    // populated on initial request
    string Name { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<Subscriber> Subscribers { get; set; }

    // the data in question - keep it here?
    IEnumerable<Post> SubscriberPosts { get; set; }
}
```

**ProfileController.cs**

```
public class ProfileController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View( new ProfileViewModel()
        {
            Name = GetUserName(),
            Subscribers = GetAllSubscribers()
        });
    }

    public GetSubscriberPosts( string id )
    {
        // do stuff to get posts
    }
}
```

**ProfileView.cshtml**

```
@using MyNamespace.Models.ProfileViewModel
<div id="Profile">
    <h1>@Model.Name</h1>
    <ul>
        @{
             foreach(var subscriber in @Model.Subscribers)
             {
                 <li><a onclick="PreviewSubscriberPosts('@subscriber.UserID')">@subscriber.Name</a></li>
             }
         }
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="SubscriberPostsPreview">
    <!-- show some stuff here based on the selected subscriber -->
</div>
<script>
    $("#SubscriberPostsPreview").hide();

    function PreviewSubscriberPosts(userID) {
        // get the subsribers posts
        $.get("/Path/To/GetSubscriberPosts", { id = userID }, function (data) {
            // add data to the document
        });

        $("#SubscriberPostsPreview").show();
    }
</script>
```

I can see an answer to my question in two ways, but am sure that someone has a better answer to the question.

(Btw, from my understanding, the properties defined in a View Model can represent both data you want to display, and also data that you want to get as input from the user)

**Answer A**
The View Model represents the data you want to show in the view, so define it all in the View Model.

**Answer B**
Because the data has to be loaded after the page using Ajax and because the data won't be changed by the user, there's no reason to define the data in the View Model.

I'm leaning towards Answer B, but looking for someone else's input.

Comment: Just because it is being loaded via ajax as opposed to on initial page load doesn't really make much of a difference.  If it were me I would define a view model for it.  If I had a set of incoming data (from user input) which varies greatly from the original view model then I would declare that in a "Request Model".  Doing this kind of thing makes upkeep of the application much easier.

Comment: When you say "the View Model" are you referring to the model used for the original page load? Some code examples will help us understand your context.

Comment: @nurdyguy this makes sense, so your "Request Model" is essentially a View Model that is populated on a request subsequent to the view loading? and when that data is returned to the view from the Ajax call, you must populate your view using something on the client-side (obviously), so rather than using razor to display the data, you select and populate the html with js/jquery? if you wanted to make an answer out of this go ahead

Comment: Depend on your application , is it senstive then you have to used view model , If not you can use dirrect entity class to load data to view. its up to you . BUT i will recommend you always use viewmodel.

Comment: @Jasen just added code for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of a view model is to encapsulate the data which is being used in a view.  Whether it is being used in a view on page load or as the response to an ajax call really doesn't matter.  If the data involved is as simple as a string or maybe just a list/array of ints, then I probably wouldn't worry about it.  But if it involves much more than that then encapsulating it in a vm is recommended.

If the request being sent varies much from a view model then I would recommend creating a new model for it.  This is often called a request model.  The term "request model" is more often used to describe an api request but the same basic idea exists here.  You have a request going to a server and the request involves a somewhat complex set of data.  So you encapsulate the data in a model and let model binding work its magic.  This will also make the server side code much cleaner and easier to maintain.

Both request models and view models are DTOs, Data Transfer Objects (see also POCO).  These objects typically don't have user defined constructors (though they *can* when needed) but they are great for creating cleaner code with his easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you would have 2 different ViewModels. One for the initial index request and one for the ajax request. SubscriberPosts would only be a property on the ajax request ViewModel. Typically for Ajax requests I just keep my ViewModel as an anonymous object instead of defining a class.